# how to get multiple radiobutton values

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am planning to have dynamic number of radioButtons as the number of rows returned by SQL query to the DB.

How do I code "variable" for RadioButtons dynamically, so that upon selection I get separate value for all the radio buttons.

For each result return from DB, i have a Yes/No radioButton.

```
i = 0
for r in self.results :
    print(r)
    globals()[r[0]] = tk.IntVar()
    R1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.win1, text="Yes", variable=globals()[r[0]], value=1)
    R2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.win1, text="No", variable=globals()[r[0]], value=2)
    R1.grid( column=2, row=i+2)
    R2.grid( column=3, row=i+2)

    item_Label = ttk.Label(self.win1, text=r[0])
    item_Label.grid(column=0, row=i+2)
    resp = globals()[r[0]].get()
    print(resp)
    i += 1
```

I am getting the error as "

```
KeyError: 'object1'
```

where object1 is the result returned from DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to reproduce your problem in a similar way and hopefully you will get the idea.

What you can do is create a list of `IntVar()` which will be used for each pair of *Radiobuttons* used per row of the query result.

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()

def show_values():
    a = " ".join([str(i.get()) for i in values])
    tk.Label(win, text=a).grid()

results = ["RB1: ", "RB2: ", "RB3: "]
values = [tk.IntVar() for i in range(len(results))]
i = 0
for r in results:
    r1 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text="Yes", variable=values[i], value=1)
    r2 = tk.Radiobutton(win, text="No", variable=values[i], value=2)
    r1.grid(column=1, row=i)
    r2.grid(column=2, row=i)

    item_Label = tk.Label(win, text=r)
    item_Label.grid(column=0, row=i)
    i += 1

tk.Button(win, text='Show Values', command=show_values).grid(columnspan=2)

win.mainloop()
```

[image]